# Count number of characters in Haskell MapReduce code

Tags: mapreduce, haskell

In Haskell code from Real World Haskell, Chapter 24, an example of using MapReduce to count the number of LINES in a file is implemented as follows:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count '\n')
                      rdeepseq sum
```

It's clear to me that this is counting the number of newline characters. If I wanted to count the number of a's, I do:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count 'a')
                      rdeepseq sum
```

I've tried this, and it works. How do I modify this code to count the number of characters (ie total number of characters present? Is there some sort of regular expression framework I can use?

Comment: Use `LB.length` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's clear to me that this is counting the number of newline characters.

Well, not really. A `ByteString` is a string of bytes. (If you want a string of characters, you should use `Text` from either [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text.html) or [Data.Text.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy.html), in the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package.)

Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 exports an interface that lets you pretend you're working with characters, but it assumes one character = one byte, à la ISO-8859-1 or ASCII. Unicode it ain't.

> How do I modify this code to count the number of characters (ie total number of characters present?

[`LB.count :: Char -> ByteString -> Int64`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/bytestring-0.10.0.2/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v%3acount), so we're looking for a function of type `ByteString -> Int64`. That function is [`LB.length`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/bytestring-0.10.0.2/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v%3alength).

```
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq LB.length
                      rdeepseq sum
```

> Is there some sort of regular expression framework I can use?

It's easy enough to use full-blown parsers in Haskell that we (well, I at least) use parsers instead of regular expressions. If your data is in the form of a `ByteString` (or a `Text`, for that matter) I'd recommend using [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec).